# Using local sqlexpress with EF speeds up performance more than expected. Why?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a C# .NET 4.5 Console application using Entity Framework 6.1 and
I use the Unit of Work pattern.  Typical example of code where I need to add an entry to my tblFills table:

```
    var fillRep = UnitOfWork.Instance.GetRepository<tblFills>();

    fillRep.Add(fill);

    UnitOfWork.Instance.Commit();
```

One of my simulations makes 900 database writes.

Using a remote server (hosting SQL Server on a remote cloud server), my simulation takes 6:21 minutes (6 minutes, 21 seconds). That's an average of 25 seconds per transaction (it is doing other things as well).
At the start of my code, I make 10 database writes to a dummy table to time it... then devide by 10 to get my average database access time.   This simulation showed a 61ms access time.

My performance test code:

```
 Private void SqlPerformanceTest()
{
    Logger.Debug("Starting SQL Performance Test...");
    int iterations = 10;
    TempPerformance tp = new TempPerformance();
    tp.Quantity = 10;
    TimeSpan startTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Instance.GetRepository<TempPerformance>().Add(tp);
        UnitOfWork.Instance.Commit();
    }
    DateTime elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
    Logger.Debug("Done. Average SQL access for adding entires is: {0} ms", elapsedTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / iterations);
}
```

**I then switch my connection string to a local SQLEXPRESS instance i have running and my simulation time goes from over 6 minutes to 10 seconds.**

This makes no sense to me since I believe that my database access times are the only difference in the two simulation.

Can someone help me understand?

To summarize:
1) Using external database with database access times of 61 ms, doing 900 writes to database, simulation takes over 6 minutes.
2) Using local database, same simulation takes 10 seconds.

Any help or pointers would be truly appreciated.

My remote server is running SQL Server 2014 on a Windows 2008 Server R2 Datacenter.   I don't think this matters since I measure access times but thought I'd mention it.

Thanks
-Ed

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is in this sentence: **remote cloud server**

It's not database access times, but network latency time that counts here. Your application might be quite chatty depending on how repository and service client is implemented. Locally it doesn't matter, but using cloud makes tons of difference.

Please make sure you run test your app deployed remotely (ie. not from your local PC connecting to remote SQL Server). Check database settings for geolocation, so you are sure database server and app server are within same location and perfectly within same datacenter.

But be aware that you will never achieve as great results as single-tier (sql+app server hosted on the same machine), because this scenario don't use network interface at all.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I understand your reply... wouldn't the 61ms round-trip measurement I made above measure exactly that: server + SQL latency?  But I agree with your last statement that I will try to implement app+db on the same server though I will need a mirror somehow...